# How to resolve hostname to an ip address in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip-address, hostname, hosts

I need to resolve hostname defined in hosts file to its corresponding IP address.

For example my host file look like this - "/etc/hosts"

```
127.0.0.1    ggns2dss81 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
192.168.253.8    abcdserver
192.168.253.20   testwsserver
```

Now in my `node.js`, i can read content of this file, but i need to fetch for given `hostname`.

```
hostname = "testwsserver"
hostIP = getIP(hostname);
console.log(hostIP); // This should print 192.168.253.20
```

**PS** - `npm pkg` or any third party package cannot be installed on machine.

Help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

How about [NodeJS documentation - DNS](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) – have you checked it?

```
const dns = require('dns')

dns.lookup('testwsserver', function(err, result) {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Just to build on **Krzysztof Safjanowski**'s answer,

you can also use the builtin *promisify* utility to convert it to a promise rather than a callback.

```js
const util = require('util');
const dns = require('dns');
const lookup = util.promisify(dns.lookup);

try {
  result = await lookup('google.com')
  console.log(result)
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: A bit superfluous when the `dns` module already has [Promise support built-in](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/dns.html) :) Just do `const {lookup} = require('dns').promises`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using standard [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
import { default as dns } from 'dns';

async function getIP(hostname)
{
    let obj = await dns.promises.lookup(hostname).catch((error)=>
    {
        console.error(error);
    });
    return obj?.address;
}

async function main()
{
    let hostname = "stackoverflow.com";
    let hostIP = await getIP(hostname);
    console.log(`IP Address of ${hostname}:`, hostIP);
}
main();
```

You'd save this to a file ending with the extension `mjs` instead of `js`, so that node will know we're using the ES6 module's `import` statement instead of the commonJS `require` statement.